How to write an alias of form Alias<T, N> that yields std::tuple<T1, T2, ... TN>
Example: Ts<int, 5> ints; //decltype(ints) = std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>
Other Example: Ts<std::string, 3> strs; //decltype(strs) = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>;
I tried writing this code to achieve this:
namespace detail {
    template<typename Tuple, typename TupleElem, size_t N>
    struct TypeRecursion {
        using Type = std::conditional_t<
            std::tuple_size_v<Tuple> == N, 
            Tuple,
            typename TypeRecursion<decltype(std::tuple_cat(Tuple{}, std::tuple<TupleElem>{})), TupleElem, N>::Type
        >;
    };
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
using Ts = typename detail::TypeRecursion<std::tuple<T>, T, N>::Type;

But MSVC gives me the error: recursive type or function dependency too complex. I looked at the compiler output, and whenever I tried to enter a Ts<T, N> it tried to make a std::tuple of a zillion T, so I think somehow the base case is wrong for my class template TypeRecursion. I don't see why, though.

Dupe: How to create a type list (for variadic templates) that contains n-times the same type?

You can just std::tuple_cat std::array:
template<class T, std::size_t N>
using Ts = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<std::array<T, N>>()));

Demo

It should be note this is not guaranteed behavior until C++23.  Before then it was allowed for implementations to implement this behavior but it is UB if they did not.
